# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python

This is my coding:

```
#Getting them to import their code:
number = int(input("Enter 7 digit GTIN code to get eighth number : "))

#importing math for subtracting later:
import math

#Getting the numbers X3 & X1 and then adding them:
def eight(total):
    multiplier = [3, 1]
    total = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(str(number)):
        total = total + int(digit)*multiplier[i%2]

#Subtracting the total to get the last number:
        nearest_10 = int(math.ceil(total / 10.0)) * 10
        return nearest_10 - total


code = number,eight(number)
code = int(code)
print(code)

#printing their full number:



#Checking the validity of the eight digit GTIN-8 code:

def validity(valid):
    multiplier = [3, 1]
    valid = 0
    string = ""
    for i, digit in enumerate(list(str(code))):
         valid = valid + str(digit)*multiplier[i%2]
         string = string+str(str(digit)*multiplier[i%2])+", "

    if code % 10 == 0:
        print"Valid"
    else:
        print"Not valid"
```

However when I am trying to convert my code to an integer for later, as it needs to be a single integer for the answer, it says this:

```
code = int(code)
TypeError: int() 
argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Comment: I reformatted your code to fit this site better, but the indentation seems off. Please check.

Comment: What is code=number, eight(number) supposed to do?

Comment: `code=number, eight(number)` so now `code` is tuple contains 2 values: `number` and `eight(number)` https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples

Comment: the indentation is the same as my coding, if it seems off it probably is I am only a basic coder at school and this is one of our hardest pieces of coding yet :/

Comment: The answer needs to include the original number that was input 'number' and the number created from the function 'eight(total)' as one 8 digit number

Comment: `print(str(number) + '\t' + str(eight(total)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to fix this is to concatenate the numbers as a string and do an int() on the resulting string . Something like :

```
code = '%s%s' % (number,eight(number))
code = int(code)
print(code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
code = number,eight(number)
```

Makes code to be a binary tuple, `(number, eight(number))`. Python adds the parentheses and makes a tuple, as it often does behind the scenes to allow for prettier code. Your next line then tries to take the `int()` of that, which is not allowed.

I don't know what you want with `eight(number)`, but it is not clear why you are trying to take `int()` here, since both `number` and `eight(number)` seem to be integers already. What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: I am trying to get the 7 digit number that has been input as a single number including the number that is created from the function eight(total). SO there is an eight digit number created that I can work with such as divide by ten

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers make sense, but as Rory Daulton points out, you seem to be working with integers already. To avoid making tuples and stay in integers, say
code=10*number+eight(number)

and go straight to printing.

Answer (score 0):

`code = number,eight(number)
 code = int(code)`

You are creating a tuple here. number,eight(number) is a tuple. It has 2 values, how can it be converted to `int`?